# Is it possible in Ruby to print a part of a regex (group) and instead of the whole matched substring?

Tags: ruby, regex, sed, pattern-matching, gsub

Is it possible in `sed` may be even in Ruby to memorize the matched part of a pattern and print it instead of the full string which was matched:

```
"aaaaaa bbb ccc".strip.gsub(/([a-z])+/, \1) # \1 as a part of the regex which I would like to remember and print then instead of the matched string.
# => "a b c"
```

I thing in `sed` it should be possible with its `h` = `holdspace` command or similar, but what also about Ruby?

Comment: You are missing `'\1'` here. Or did you mean to use `\1` after this line? for example `some_var = \1` ?

Comment: I thought to use `\1` as in the `sed` when you want to print only the part of the pattern: the first group of regex in clauses

Comment: Consider changing the title to something meaningful.

Comment: That is the worst title I've ever seen on SO.  Not only is it meaningless, but it suggests laziness on your part.  Clear, accurate titles serve an important purpose.  Please change it.

Comment: my bad, forgot to complete the title when wanted to change it (was disturbed by smth. while writing). it was unintentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. Here are few example:

```
print "aaaaaa bbb ccc".strip.gsub(/([a-z])+/, '\1')
# => "a b c"
```

And,

```
print "aaaaaa bbb ccc".strip.scan(/([a-z])+/).flatten
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`"aaaaaa bbb ccc".split`

and then join that array back together with the first character of each element

`[a[0][0,1], a[1][0,1], a[2][0,1], a[3][0,1], ... ].join(" ")`

@glennjackman's suggestion: `ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.map {|w| w[0]}.join(" ")'`

Comment: then I get `["aaaaaa","bbb","ccc"]` when split and again "aaaaaa bbb ccc" when join, but no "a b c"

Comment: @static, Answer updated again for better compatibility

Comment: you mean I should explicitly write each `a[i][0,1]`? even so, it still doesn't work

Comment: something like `ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.map {|w| w[0]}.join(" ")'`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is grep:

```
echo "aaaaaa bbb ccc" | grep -o '\<.'
```